# Create table without omitting empty rows?

Tags: sql, create-table

I have a short question but no reproducible sample as I simply use the standard function for now.

I want to use SQL's `CREATE TABLE` function. However, I want the table to display rows even if there are no data points for that specific ovbservation. Currently, whenever there is no data for a certain row, the whole row gets omitted. Ideally I'd like it to still display the row for that specific date, and just have empty cells wher ethe data is missing.

This is important because I need the table to be of specific size, even if data is missing.

One idea I had was to include a `WHERE ROWNUM` statement, which refers to a materialised view or table of exactly the size I want the table to be in. Is this possible? Any other solution is welcome.

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do. What problem are you trying to resolve ? There are big "smell" in your question

Comment: Well like I said, I need to create a table that has a specific size no matter the data availabilty. I don't quite understand the sentiment of your comment.

Comment: Not enough specific information..such as table structure, sample data, reasons for the "omissions", etc.

Comment: You seem to have a wrong solution. I'm maybe wrong but you seem to speak about HTML table... What is your data structure, what are your table  ? Give some data to help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create table first of all.

use insert statement to insert all the required rows at once (empty rows with only date, or rowindex)

'View' idea is not better, because you have to show those record (empty rows to enter data perhaps) to user, so if user enters data in 5th rows, you will not be able to add 5th row in table prior to first 4 rows.